# django rest swagger unable to read api

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

I have set up the url as this in urls.py

```
url(r'^', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls', namespace='swagger')),
```

For the reason I do not understand, after the swagger API UI load from *localhost:8000*. None of the API can be expand with this error:

```
Unable to read api 'user' from path http://localhost:8000/api-docs/api/v1/user
```

I thought it is the issue with the api-docs in the url but after remove that and re-fetch again. I get these:

```
fetching resource list: http://localhost:8000/
```

Which I got no response after this after, or I get this if I add /api/v1 to the url

```
403 : undefined http://localhost:8000/api/v1
```

This is what I have in the settings.py for swagger:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "exclude_namespaces": [], # List URL namespaces to ignore
    "api_version": 'alpha 1.0', # API's version
    "api_path": "/", # the path to API (it could not be a root level)
    "enabled_methods" : [ # method to enable in Swagger UI
        'get',
        'post',
        'delete'
    ],
    "api_key": '', # An API key
    "is_authentcated": False, # Set to True to enforce user authentication,
    "is_superuser": False, # Set to True to enforce admin only access
}
```

Anyone know what I did wrong here? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I got similar error. In my case there was missing commas in my fields specification in the fields. i.e.

I had this:

fields = ( 'id', 'company_info' 'serial_number', 'last_used_lat_lng', 'sensor_type', 'update_timestamp', 'last_used_tech')

Instead of this

fields = ( 'id', 'company_info', 'serial_number', 'last_used_lat_lng', 'sensor_type', 'update_timestamp', 'last_used_tech')

Comment: @SubodhNijsure My case was a bit interesting, I was using a third party plugin that has urls in it. Somehow that resolved this issue... I removed the plugin and then everything worked out fine. I still don't know what exactly is the issue though.

Comment: In my case I got this error because I had a collision between a ViewSet and a generics.ListAPIView in the urls.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to @SubodhNijsure, I had runtime errors for the endpoint in question. Trying a URL with the `/api-docs/` prefix seems to be Swagger's way of failing when its JSON call for the endpoint information fails.

Solution: fix my runtime errors.